# What is the function that gets triggered when the Google sign feature gets cancelled?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-signin, bloc

I'm creating a **Flutter** app and I'm implementing an authentification feature with **Google Sign In** using the `google_sign_in` package. I want to handle the case where the user cancels the authentification process, in order to show a message or remove the loading screen. How can I implement that ?

Answer (score 1):

I use this method

```
  void _handleSilentSignIn() async {
try {
  GoogleSignInAccount account = await _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
  if (account == null) {
    print('User canceled sign-in');
  } else {
    print('User signed in: ${account.displayName}');
  }
} catch (error) {
  print(error);
}
```

Either the user is logged in, or it returns null if the user cancels the login process.